# How to set List view Using Custom adapter?How custom adapter works in the code given below?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter, json

I tried various method.I am using a text view and a button in each row in list.When i run the code i am getting **null pointerexception**.Is it necessary to use view holder in this example?I also added view in one example and tried but bad luck.Check the code below.

```
 adapter1= new custadapter(this, R.layout.lisarrange, todisplay);
 listview.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

custadapter.java

```
public class custadapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

Itemdatabase database;
String idstring;

private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;
ArrayList<JSONObject> list;


public custadapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<JSONObject> _list) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId,_list);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.list = _list;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}


@Override
public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row= convertView;
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    if (convertView == null){
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lisarrange, parent, false);
              }
    TextView titlerow = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txttitleview);

    Button btnrow = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btndel);


    try {
        titlerow.setText(list.get(position).getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    btnrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                idstring = list.get(position).getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int id1=Integer.valueOf(idstring);
            database.deleteContact(id1);
        }
    });

    return row;
}




}
```

Another Code i tried is

bseadapter.java which extends Baseadapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.lisarrange, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.titlerow = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttitleview);
        holder.btnrow=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btndel);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    JSONObject listtemp = list.get(position);

    try {
        holder.titlerow.setText(listtemp.getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.btnrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                idstring = list.get(position).getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    int id1=Integer.valueOf(idstring);
    database.deleteContact(id1);

    return convertView;



}

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView titlerow;
    Button btnrow;
}
```

}

Logcat

```
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at com.examplenotetest.bseadapter.getView(bseadapter.java:75)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1259)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1171)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5245)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16831)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2189)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1535)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
01-16 12:12:38.005: E/AndroidRuntime(27502):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where are you getting nullpointerexception post your logcat also

Comment: @zyonneo: which code currently you are using for getView method ?

Comment: Using a view holder is never necessary. It needs to be done so that android can display views efficiently.

Comment: I think your `database` object null. You haven't initialized it.

Comment: are you sure this where the exception happens? logcat says it happens in bseadapter.java not custadapter

Comment: i tried two adapters...but none workd for me..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly make sure you are looking at the class that throws the exception, according to logcat this is **bseadapter.java**.

Secondly, if you assign a value to variable **idstring** inside the onClickListener you will have to declare it as final. The same applies to **position** which you also use inside of the listener. You might want to rethink the way you do this clicking flow, as it is there it wont work.

Thirdly, replace the following line

```
JSONObject listtemp = (JSONObject)list.get(position); //this isn't wrong per se, but use the functions thats intended for this pupose
```

with

```
JSONObject listtemp = getItem(position);
```

Then before doing any of the other code check that listtemp is not null. Wrap the rest of the code inside this if statement:

```
if(listtemp != null){
   //do all your stuff here
}
```

Fourthly,where you do

```
listtemp.getString("name")
```

you must first check that **list** is not null (hence the *if(listtemp != null)* as mentioned earlier). Then you cannot asume the **listtemp** has property **name**. So always use

```
optString("name")
```

instead of

```
getString("name")
```

Have a look at the JsonObject documentation for more info on
[optString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Finally make sure **Itemdatabase database** is initialized

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using ArrayAdapter class so you need not override getCount() and getItem() etc. methods as you are dealing with array of data.

Simply you just need to override only one method i.e. getView() and perform all action over that.

For your reference try below code :

```
BusinessOwnerArrayAdapter boaa = new BusinessOwnerArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), m_ArrayList, this);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.business_owner_list);
            lv.setAdapter(boaa);
```

Above `m_ArrayList` is arraylist.

`boaa` is ArrayAdapter class

and `lv` is your listview.

Now you ArrayAdapter class would look like this ..

```
/**
 * @author VIVEK
 * All Product Info list array adapter class.
 */
public class ClaimSummaryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClaimSummaryModel> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<ClaimSummaryModel> values;
    ImageLoader imgLoader;
    String _activityString;
    ClaimsSummaryFragment ubf;
    CommonMethodStuff cms;

    public ClaimSummaryArrayAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<ClaimSummaryModel> values, ClaimsSummaryFragment ubf) {
        super(context, R.layout.claim_summary_row, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        cms = new CommonMethodStuff();
        this.ubf = ubf;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claim_summary_row, parent, false);

        final ClaimSummaryModel model = values.get(position);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf" );
        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Semibold.ttf" );

        TextView promotion_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.promotion_name_claim);
        promotion_name.setTypeface(font1);
        if(model.promotion_name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            promotion_name.setText("");
        else
            promotion_name.setText(cms.toTheUpperCaseSingle(model.promotion_name));

        TextView product_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        //product_name.setTypeface(font);
        if(model.product_name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            product_name.setText("");
        else
            product_name.setText(cms.toTheUpperCaseSingle(model.product_name));


        TextView serial_number = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.serial_number);
        serial_number.setTypeface(font);
        serial_number.setText(model.serial_number);

        return rowView;
    }
```

Hope this clarifies your need. Let me know if any concern in same.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
```

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
ViewHolder holder;
if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.lisarrange, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.titlerow = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttitleview);
    holder.btnrow=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btndel);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

} else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

JSONObject listtemp = list.get(position);

try {
    holder.titlerow.setText(listtemp.getString("name"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

holder.btnrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            idstring = list.get(position).getString("id");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});

int id1=**Integer.valueOf(idstring);***emphasized text*
database.deleteContact(id1);

return convertView;
```

}

For the very first time when your list view will be getting filled by the adapter in Integer.valueOf(idstring); statement the idstring will be null so it is giving you NullPointerException.